# Cordova clipboard fails to paste

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In an ionic app page controller there's this piece of code that's triggered when a button is clicked with the value of a telephone number, email, or other contact information. When the button is clicked, the value of the text makes it to the toast and renders ok. But when I then go to another app in iOS to paste the text nothing is pasted.

```
async copyToClipboard(text : string){
  try{
    await this.clipboard.copy(text);

    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Copied ' + text,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'bottom',
      dismissOnPageChange : true
    });

    toast.present();
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - can't paste in another app, but if I open some webpage in Chrome which contains textbox, I can paste there, so copied information is in clipboard, but with some weird restriction.

Comment: Did you check if you have the clipboard cordova plugin installed? Usually when native plugins work in the browser and not in the app it's because the npm ionic/native module was installed but not the cordova plugin. You can do this by running: ionic cordova plugin

Comment: @NullIsNot0 Think the solution may have been found, check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue affecting iOS 9, 10, 11 so it's surprising that the bug has been left untouched like that. A look at the plugin's github repo issues yields a solution.

In your plugin's src/ios/CDVClipboard.m file make the following change.

Replace this line

```
[pasteboard setValue:text forPasteboardType:@"public.text"];
```

With this line:

```
pasteboard.string = text;
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Here is the github repo issue: https://github.com/XPanniX/CordovaClipboard/pull/1/commits/dac4c0e5eb29fbccbc9c6f9c0e8c45971b5deea7

Comment: Ingenting, all the best!